# .Net Core Authentication with local active directory

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, asp.net-core

I'm completly new to .Net Core 1.0.1 and currently I'm freaking out about the authentication process with a local AD.
I'm trying to implement a new webpage as an intranet application but I can't use windows authentication, because there is a requirement to login on this page from every computer in the company without changing the logged on windows user.
So I've implemented a login field with username and password.
But I can't figure out how I can use authentication to a local AD inside my company. No Azure AD is available.
Novell.LDAP does not work with my dependencies.
Hopefully you can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PrincipalContext` class by including `System.DirectoryServices` and `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` libraries. Then call `ValidateCredentials` upon that context as follows:

```
var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, dc.HostName, dc.UserName, dc.Password);

bool authenticated = context.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
```

The `PrincipalContext` constructor and `ValidateCredentials` method have many overloads. And chosing which one to call them is merely up to your system. Hence checking [this document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) would help you along the way.